# Non-exact D.E with Integration Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ DE : (y^2)dx + (x^2-xy)dy = 0 $

$ \frac{ \delta M } {\delta y} = 2y $ 
 and $ \frac{ \delta N } {\delta x} = 2x-y $

I've found the Integrating factor to be:

$ e^\int\ \frac{((\delta M/\delta y) - (\delta N/\delta x))}{N} \  $
 = $ \frac {x-y}{x^3}\ $

However after multiplying the Integrating factor with the initial equations , they don't seem to be becoming exact.

$ \delta M  * \frac {x-y}{x^3} = y^2 *  \frac {x-y}{x^3} $ 
and $ \delta  N * \frac {x-y}{x^3} = x^2-xy *  \frac {x-y}{x^3}  $

After differentiating the new $ \delta M $ and $ \delta N $

$ \frac{\delta M } {\delta y} = - \frac {y(3y-2x)}{x^3} = \frac {-3y^2+2xy}{x^3}  $
and $ \frac{\delta N } {\delta x} =  \frac {2y(x-y)}{x^3} = \frac {-2y^2 + 2xy}{x^3}  $

As you can see they are not exact, even though they should be. I don't know where I've made an error exactly but it seems that it's most likely in the calculation of the Integrating factor? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do unfortunately. It's part of my differential equations coursework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrating factor only works if $\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial M }{\partial y } - \dfrac{\partial N }{\partial x }}{N}$ is only in terms of $x$.

Fortunately, the equation is homogeneous. Homogeneous equations can be solved using the substitution $y = u x$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x \dfrac{du}{dx} + u$, from the Product Rule.

$y^2dx + (x^2 - xy)dy = 0$ can be rewritten as $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y^2}{xy - x^2}$, which simplifies to the following separable equation:

$$x \dfrac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{u-1}$$